# Using footnotes with moderncv class in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have the following problem: I would like to use footnotes together with the moderncv documentclass. In my case it gives me an error if I try to compile the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}

\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}

\begin{document}
\section{Start}
Hello\footnote{this is a footnote}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \H@@footnotetext ...color@begingroup \@makefntext 
>                                                     {\rule \z@ \footnotesep \i...
>   l.9 Hello\footnote{this is a footnote}

I am not sure why, but obviously the moderncv documentclass is to blame for this error, if I change the documentclass to article it works.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that the same error happens when [importing the longfbox package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696408/17107), fortunately the `footmisc` fix also works for this case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try the [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/) package. I.e. change the beginning to

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{footmisc} % enabling footnotes.
\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
% ... rest the same.
```

Comment: The problem is, the footnotes appear after the cventry, and not at the bottom of the page. Is it possible to put them right at the bottom?

Answer (score 5):

To put footnotes on the bottom of the page, you need to see this topic:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48500/footnote-in-moderncv

It solves my problem about footnotes. You should use \footnotemark and \footnotetext{Some text} instead of \footnote